# Error: array_flip() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel, getting the following error,

> array_flip() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

```
in GuardsAttributes.php line 188
at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'array_flip() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given', '/Users/aaronmk2/Desktop/CodingDojo/php/onetoone/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/GuardsAttributes.php', 188, array('attributes' => array('name' => '2250 nw 59st Seattle, WA 98107')))
at array_flip('name') in GuardsAttributes.php line 188
at Model->fillableFromArray(array('name' => '2250 nw 59st Seattle, WA 98107')) in Model.php line 216
at Model->fill(array('name' => '2250 nw 59st Seattle, WA 98107')) in Model.php line 145
at Model->__construct(array('name' => '2250 nw 59st Seattle, WA 98107')) in web.php line 24
```

Here is the code that is creating the problem

```
Route::get('/insert', function(){
    $user = User::findOrFail(1);

    $address = new Address(['name' => '2250 nw 59st Seattle, WA 98107']);

    $user->address()->save( $address);
});
```

What is the issue and how can I fix it.

Comment: I think you don't need to pass `$address` as an argument to  `save `. [See eloquent docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models)

Comment: @Alex2php, I looked at the documentation and tried with out using address in save.  The issue is with the previous line.

Comment: @Alex2php his code is correct. Look at the examples in [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you'll look into 5.4 source code, you'll see that this error occurs because you have defined `$fillable` property as a string, like:

```
protected $fillable = 'name';
```

But it should be an array:

```
protected $fillable = ['name'];
```